# Low cost airfare for each country

Tags: air-travel, planning, fares, flight-search-engines

I'm planning to travel with my best friend this summer and I was wondering if any of you guys know a website that list low cost airfare for each country?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Air fares are not segregated by countries, quite often planes fly between different countries.

Comment: Some search engines (Skyscanner I think and Adioso for example) let you select a whole country as destination and then suggest the cheapest fares they can find. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Understand that published fares are one thing; availability is another. Just because an airline sells a particular seat for a particular price does not mean *you* will be the one to buy it at that price.

Comment: There are a truckload of questions on this site that deal with finding cheap airfare.

Comment: www.hipmunk.com sometimes excellent.www.adioso,com quirky but can be good.  Expedia CLAIM to beat anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly it's a bit outdated, but used to be a good starting point.
Most of the routes still apply. It's possible that there are new ones that are not listed yet.

http://www.flycheapo.com/

In any case keep in mind that you are looking for cheap prices, not for low cot companies. It's not uncommon that a traditional company can provide a cheaper price in specific conditions or a cheaper solution (eg. the ticket might be more expensive but you land in a near airport to destination therefor reducing transfer costs). I would give a try on a fare search engine like [skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/), [momondo](http://www.momondo.com/) or [kayak](http://www.kayak.com/). Each has its own strengths. In skyscanner, for example, you can even do searches like cheapest prices for a given month or to a given country, instead of a city in case that suits you. You will get prices for both low cost and traditional companies and you will be able to compare the best solution.

Ryanair used to be outside these results since they didn't allow fare search engines to get their info. You would need to go directly to their website. Currently that no longer happens.
I am not aware if there are other companies with the same policy, that are worth looking directly on their website.

Comment: It's all very well booking with Ryanair - **BUT**  THEN you'd have to fly with them !!!! (Or try to)

Comment: @JonathanReez thanks, but I mention that - "that no longer happens"

Comment: @nsn Thank you for taking time to respond in this query. We decided to go to Thailand and I checked Skyscanner's rates. I think we'll be ready to book our flight next week.